# Getting error while importing pynput.mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, importerror, pynput

I'm having an issue with this pynput.mouse call.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mac/Desktop/Python Projects/autoclicker/autoclicker.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
ImportError: No module named pynput.mouse
```

I tried reinstalling Pynput with Python3 -m pip install pynput and pip3 install pynput in the virtual evironment but nothing has changed. I have tried using python interpreters 3.11.2, 3.10, 3.9, and 2.7.

Comment: Do you have, by any chance a file called `pynput.py` in `/Users/Mac/Desktop/Python Projects/autoclicker`? How are you executing your python script?